# i need help to put 3 boxes in one line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on simple HTML web but I am stuck on something like 3 boxes I want accordingly in one line  you can check the screenshot of example for that how I want  I tried many times to do by every way but I failed to solve or sort out this issue kindly please help me in that

see this screenshot how it showing

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the example

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="property-wrap mb-2 row no-gutter" id="pp">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-20">
    <div class="ppt-list list-vw mb-30 featured" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.location.href='https://supershop.ng/smart1'">
      <figure id="mfs">
        <!-- <span class="tag left text-uppercase bg-dark">$5,70,0000</span>
                                            <span class="tag right text-uppercase primary-bg">for rent</span> -->
        <a href="https://supershop.ng/smart1" class="image-effect overlay">
          <img src="assets/images/smart1-logo.svg" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 100px;" id="mis">
        </a>
      </figure>
      <!--fig-->

      <div class="content" id="mcs">
        <h4 class="mb-0"><a href="https://supershop.ng/smart1">SuperShopper</a></h4>
        <div class="mb-15">
          <p>Lekki Phase 1, Lekki</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--content-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="ppt-list list-vw mb-30 featured" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.location.href='https://supershop.ng/green_way'">
      <figure id="mfs">
        <!-- <span class="tag left text-uppercase bg-dark">$5,70,0000</span>
                                            <span class="tag right text-uppercase primary-bg">for rent</span> -->
        <a href="https://supershop.ng/green_way" class="image-effect overlay">
          <img src="assets/images/green_way.png" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 100px;" id="mis">
        </a>
      </figure>
      <!--fig-->

      <div class="content" id="mcs">
        <h4 class="mb-0"><a href="https://supershop.ng/green_way">GreenWay Supermarket</a></h4>
        <div class="mb-15">
          <p>142 Lekki - Epe Expressway, Beside Monarch Event Center, Lekki</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--content-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="ppt-list list-vw mb-30 featured" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.location.href='https://supershop.ng/pjv1'">
      <figure id="mfs">
        <!-- <span class="tag left text-uppercase bg-dark">$5,70,0000</span>
                                            <span class="tag right text-uppercase bg-blue">for sale</span> -->
        <a href="#" class="image-effect overlay">
          <img src="assets/images/pjv.png" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 0px;" id="mis">
        </a>
      </figure>
      <!--fig-->

      <div class="content" id="mcs">
        <h4 class="mb-0"><a href="https://supershop.ng/pjv1">PJV Supermarket</a></h4>
        <div class="mb-15">
          <p>36b Kusenla Road, Ikate Elegushi, Lekki</p>
        </div>
        <!--content-->

      </div>
      <!--content-->


    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not much to go off of here, you haven't even included your css. Check out [mcve]

Comment: Looks like you're using a layout/style library. Please tag accordingly. If it's Bootstrap, tag your specific version.

Comment: I guessed Bootstrap 5 and added it to a snippet demo of your code. Please revise further to show the full problem. Also, Bootstrap rows should always be in a [container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/).

Comment: actually its a PWA web app i can't share css here you know can't much more code i can paste here please help me